# Conjugation Cells [equivariant cohomology]

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

I'm studying conjugation spaces, I have found in many sources that a conjugation cell is a conjugation space (without a proof). The widest approach that I have found so far is this paper ([example 3.5](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412057.pdf))

But for me is not clear the following assertions in that example:

- $\rho: H^{2k}_C(D,S)\rightarrow H^{2K}(D,S)$ is an isomorphism
- Why the injectivity of $r: H^*_C(D,S) \rightarrow H^*_C(D^\tau,S^\tau)$ is needed?
- The *conjugation equation* $r\sigma(a) = \kappa(a)u^k$ holds trivially.

I really aprreciate if someone could explain me a little bit these facts.

Answer (score 1):

As for your first question, the isomorphism
$$
\rho\colon H_C^{2k}(D,S)\rightarrow H^{2k}(D,S)
$$
follows from the spectral sequence
$$
E_2^{pq}=H^q(C,H^p(D,S))\Rightarrow H_C^{p+q}(D,S).
$$
Since $H^p(D,S)$ is nonzero only if $p=2k$, the spectral sequence degenerates at page $2$, and one gets an isomorphism
$$
H^0(G,H^{2k}(D,S))\rightarrow H_C^{2k}(D,S).
$$
Since $2k$ is even, the left-hand side is just the cohomology group $H^{2k}(D,S)$. It follows that the composition of the isomorphism with $\rho$ is the identity on $H^{2k}(D,S)$. This shows that $\rho$ is an isomorphism.